# How to use mathematical symbols in listing?

Tags: listings

I want to use math mode in lstlisting. How do I do that?
How to put tab in this mode?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]                % Start your code-block
module main()
enumerated States {$S_0$,$S_1$,$S_2$,$S_3$}
integer c;
initial : c = 0 and States = $S_0$;
endmodule
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See 4.14 Escaping to LATEX of the documentation of listings.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `escapeinside` option allows you to define how to escape from verbatim. Here's an example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]
  if foo
  list= { (*$S_1,S_2,S_3$*) }
\end{lstlisting}
```

I've used `escapeinside` to define an opening `(*` and closing `*)` escape commands. Things between `(*` and `*)` will be typeset normally. Obviously, if `(*` or `*)` are common in whatever language you're using, you should pick something else.

In fact, if all you want to do is escape maths, you can use the `mathescape` option:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
  if foo
  list= { $S_1,S_2,S_3$ }
\end{lstlisting}
```