# How to insert a custom symbol in listings?

Tags: listings

I would like to insert a custom symbol on LaTeX listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{stix}
\lstset{language=c,escapeinside={(*}{*)}}

\newcommand{\spc}{$\mathvisiblespace$}

\begin{document}

\lstinline{(*\spc*)} % Does not work

% This works
\begin{lstlisting} 
  (*\spc*)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the command `\spc` is included literally. Is there a way to allow commands in `\lstinline`?

This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63729/how-to-use-mathematical-symbols-in-listing) shows how to use `escapeinside`, but it does not work in my example. `*\spc*` is inserted literally.

Comment: escapechar and escapeinside don't work in \lstinline, only in the environment, but you can use mathescape: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43526/escaping-in-lstinline